# Change the hardcoded URL in href statement in Wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress-theming, href, customization

I have the following code in the "Mobile Repair Shop Pro" theme from LogicalThemes.

```
<div class="contan-part">
   ::before
   <p> Click the Read More button to see the entire meeting list. </p>
   <div class="btn5">
     <a href="https//staging2.xxxx.com/our-services/meetings/">
       ::before
       " Read More "
       ::after
     </a>
   </div>
<div class="clearfix">
   ::before
   ::after
</div>
```

I want to change the URL in the href statement. There are 3 occurrences of this code for different pages, and they all use the class=btn5, This theme uses the title of the services page that was set up for these as the URL to go to as well. It has to have the page set up under Services for this theme in order to create the three different boxes. Unfortunately, they don't let me enter the URL I want to go to and instead default to the same page that is used to create the individual boxes. (See attached picture of the home page.)

I have been searching online for hours for how to do this and I think JavaScript might do it, but I can't figure out the exact code I need.

I've tried creating JavaScript a few different ways, but really don't know what I'm doing with it. I don't know how to tell JS what button to watch for a click on. When I inspect the page, I can see the href statement and have changed it just to see if it would work with the new URL. It does, but I have no idea on how to make that permanent, other than going in and changing the real page that these are on.

I installed WPCode so I could use a JS snippet, but don't know what element I need to watch for as far as a button click is concerned. I've read all the posts and the first or third one might do it but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.